# How to filter a list in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a class Dog in Scala:
case class Dog(age: Int)

And a list with dogs like this:
val dogs: `List[Dog] = Dog(5) :: Dog(2) :: Dog(4) :: Nil`.

I want a list with only the dogs with age > 4, how can I do that?

Many thanks!
Vasco

Comment: With [.filter](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@filter(p:A=>Boolean):Repr)

Comment: Wow.  I'm truly impressed by the lack of effort expended by the poster.  It would *literally* have taken less time to type "filter list in scala" into a search engine and get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With `dogs.filter(_.age > 4)`