# How to append elements to list in a for loop : Scala

Tags: scala

i want to append list of elements to another list based on a condition. for example : find below code.

```
package test

object main {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
   val a = List(1,2,3,4,5)
   val b= List[Int]()
   for(x <- a){
     if (x>3){
       b:+x
     }
   }
   println(b)
 }
}
```

when i execute this i am getting empty list.

Comment: You can filter.

Comment: Can you show me how to do using conditions, i have few other conditions where i need to use loop.

Comment: Added the answer bellow, you can add more conditions in the filter or add another filter call.

Comment: recommended way is to filter in your example, also see [How to filter a list in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527830/how-to-filter-a-list-in-scala).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `List` class is immutable in Scala, so you cannot add elements to it. If you really need a mutable list, you can use `MutableList`.

```
val a = List(1,2,3,4,5)
val b= MutableList[Int]()
for (x <- a) {
  if (x > 3) {
    b += x
  }
}
println(b)
```

However, in a functional language like Scala, the best practice is to use immutable collections. Your task can be done very easily with the `filter` method.

```
val a = List(1,2,3,4,5)
val b = a.filter(_ > 3)
```

Comment: you would also need `import scala.collection.mutable.MutableList` . Not available by default

Answer (score 2):

In Scala List is an immutable collection, you can not add to it, but you can create another collection by applying filter:

```
val a = List(1,2,3,4,5)
val b = a.filter(x => x > 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, to make it much generic, you can use tabulate method to prefill your list with required n;
Example:

```
val n = 5
List.tabulate(5)(_ + 1).filter(_ > 3)
```